# AWS DMS adding a new column to track changes

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are using DMS to migrate data from MySQL to Redshift (as an ongoing migration).

We have a few large tables in MySQL - too large to add any new columns to.  However, we don't have any reliable columns in the existing table to know when a record is updated or new.

Is there a transformation in DMS that lets you a new column that contains an update timestamp, or even a fixed value that always set when the record is updated?

Comment: This is possible if S3 is being used as a target.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way now, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html -> add-column

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve that using DMS. The transformations in the DMS are pretty basic. I would encorage you to look at AWS Data pipeline if you haven't tried yet.